Could not find x-bundles (even the installation is fresh)
after openening the login page https://localhost:44314/Account/Login, I get a lot of "Could not find x-bundles" (even the installation is fresh) displayed in the console. This results in not being able to click the login button.

I used the multilayer asp.net core angular template, latest version

Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:18:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/v4-shims.css' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:19:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/toastr/toastr.min.css' for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'!
Login:20:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/select2/css/select2.min.css' for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'!
Login:21:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css' for
the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'! Login:22:17 Could not find the bundle
file '/libs/datatables.net-bs5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.css' for the
bundle 'LeptonX.Global'! Login:23:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css' for the
bundle 'LeptonX.Global'! Login:24:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:25:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/abp/utils/abp-utils.umd.min.js' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:229:21 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/abp/core/abp.js' for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'! Login:230:17
Could not find the bundle file '/libs/jquery/jquery.js' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:231:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/abp/jquery/abp.jquery.js' for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'!
Login:232:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:233:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/lodash/lodash.min.js' for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'!
Login:234:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:235:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js'
for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'! Login:236:17 Could not find the
bundle file '/libs/jquery-form/jquery.form.min.js' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:237:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/select2/js/select2.min.js' for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'!
Login:238:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:239:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/datatables.net-bs5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.js' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:240:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.min.js' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:241:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/toastr/toastr.min.js' for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'!
Login:242:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js'
for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'! Login:243:17 Could not find the
bundle file '/libs/luxon/luxon.min.js' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:244:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/abp/luxon/abp.luxon.js' for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'!
Login:245:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/timeago/jquery.timeago.js' for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'!
Login:246:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js' for the
bundle 'LeptonX.Global'! Login:247:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/moment/moment.min.js' for the bundle 'LeptonX.Global'!
Login:248:17 Could not find the bundle file
'/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js' for the bundle
'LeptonX.Global'! Login:249:17 Uncaught TypeError: abp.event is
undefined
 https://localhost:44314/libs/abp/aspnetcore-mvc-ui-theme-shared/ui-extensions.js?_v=638549833740000000:297
 https://localhost:44314/libs/abp/aspnetcore-mvc-ui-theme-shared/ui-extensions.js?_v=638549833740000000:301
ui-extensions.js:297:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 jQuery jquery-extensions.js:187:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 jQuery jquery-form-extensions.js:97:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 jQuery widget-manager.js:147:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 https://localhost:44314/libs/abp/aspnetcore-mvc-ui-theme-shared/bootstrap/dom-event-handlers.js?_v=638549833740000000:238
dom-event-handlers.js:238:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 https://localhost:44314/libs/abp/aspnetcore-mvc-ui-theme-shared/bootstrap/modal-manager.js?_v=638549833740000000:3
modal-manager.js:3:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 https://localhost:44314/libs/abp/aspnetcore-mvc-ui-theme-shared/datatables/datatables-extensions.js?_v=638549833740000000:553
datatables-extensions.js:553:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not
defined
 https://localhost:44314/libs/abp/aspnetcore-mvc-ui-theme-shared/sweetalert2/abp-sweetalert2.js?_v=638549833740000000:121 abp-sweetalert2.js:121:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not
defined
 https://localhost:44314/libs/abp/aspnetcore-mvc-ui-theme-shared/toastr/abp-toastr.js?_v=638549833740000000:4
 https://localhost:44314/libs/abp/aspnetcore-mvc-ui-theme-shared/toastr/abp-toastr.js?_v=638549833740000000:34
abp-toastr.js:4:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 https://localhost:44314/libs/abp/aspnetcore-mvc-ui-theme-shared/date-range-picker/date-range-picker-extensions.js?_v=638549833740000000:755
date-range-picker-extensions.js:755:4 Uncaught TypeError: abp.utils is
undefined
 https://localhost:44314/client-proxies/account-proxy.js?_v=638550091940000000:12
 https://localhost:44314/client-proxies/account-proxy.js?_v=638550091940000000:182
 https://localhost:44314/client-proxies/account-proxy.js?_v=638550091940000000:477
account-proxy.js:12:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 https://localhost:44314/Pages/Account/AuthorityDelegation/account-authority-delegation-global.js?_v=638550092340000000:175
account-authority-delegation-global.js:175:4 Uncaught ReferenceError:
jQuery is not defined
 https://localhost:44314/Pages/Account/LinkUsers/account-link-user-global.js?_v=638550092340000000:122
account-link-user-global.js:122:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is
not defined
 https://localhost:44314/Pages/Abp/MultiTenancy/tenant-switch.js?_v=638549833820000000:16
tenant-switch.js:16:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not
defined
306 https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/side-menu/js/lepton-x.bundle.min.js?_v=638550157860000000:2
n https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/side-menu/js/lepton-x.bundle.min.js?_v=638550157860000000:2
12 https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/side-menu/js/lepton-x.bundle.min.js?_v=638550157860000000:2
n https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/side-menu/js/lepton-x.bundle.min.js?_v=638550157860000000:2
848 https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/side-menu/js/lepton-x.bundle.min.js?_v=638550157860000000:2
n https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/side-menu/js/lepton-x.bundle.min.js?_v=638550157860000000:2
524 https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/side-menu/js/lepton-x.bundle.min.js?_v=638550157860000000:2
n https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/side-menu/js/lepton-x.bundle.min.js?_v=638550157860000000:2
 https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/side-menu/js/lepton-x.bundle.min.js?_v=638550157860000000:2
 https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/side-menu/js/lepton-x.bundle.min.js?_v=638550157860000000:2
lepton-x.bundle.min.js:2:71892 Uncaught TypeError: leptonx is
undefined
 https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/scripts/style-initializer.js?_v=638550157860000000:25
 https://localhost:44314/Themes/LeptonX/Global/scripts/style-initializer.js?_v=638550157860000000:55
style-initializer.js:25:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 https://localhost:44314/Abp/ApplicationLocalizationScript?cultureName=en:3
 https://localhost:44314/Abp/ApplicationLocalizationScript?cultureName=en:1566
ApplicationLocalizationScript:3:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not
defined
 https://localhost:44314/Abp/ApplicationConfigurationScript:3
 https://localhost:44314/Abp/ApplicationConfigurationScript:316
ApplicationConfigurationScript:3:1 Uncaught TypeError: abp.event is
undefined
 https://localhost:44314/Abp/ServiceProxyScript:4 ServiceProxyScript:4:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 https://localhost:44314/Pages/Account/Login.js?_v=638550091940000000:1
Login.js:1:1 Attempting i


Please install the ABP CLI and run the abp install-libs command to restore the assets.
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/CLI
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/CLI#install-libs
